# Who are some of the world's most recognized experts on the tailbone/coccyx?

Tags: spine, bones, ligament, pelvis-pelvic-bone, tailbone-coccyx

Does anyone know of any researchers or practitioners that have extremely deep understanding of the tailbone/coccyx?

Comment: You are asking for an opinion, which is unfortunately off-topic for this stack (and most of Stack Exchange). Please see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is really not so much a question of opinion. For example, if I asked who are some of the world's greatest experts in elliptic curves, one would not be wrong to mention names like Manjul Bhargava and Serge Lang, as these are people who have published extensively on this topic and received recognition for their work. Your comment seems to be attempting to shut down what I view as a very valid and legitimate question. There may well be people on this site who know of researchers and practitioners deeply involved in coccyx research, which would be perfectly fine answers to the question.

Comment: I will defer to the moderators as I could certainly be wrong.